# Prevent OnTouchEvent on siblings

Tags: android, touch-event, motionevent

How do I block onTouchEvent from a view's siblings?  I have a ViewGroup with a custom button in it.  When the button receives an OnTouchEvent, I want to block further OnTouchEvents from going to the button's siblings.  I *do* want to continue receiving OnTouchEvent in the button.

Comment: Is your implementation of onTouchEvent() returning true (for the custom button)?

Comment: Yes, it returns true, though not on the first event.  It waits till after a onLongClick comes through.  That much seems to be working in that it allows a parent ViewPager to receive events as long as they happen right away.

Comment: You could take a look at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a custom `ViewGroup` as well. In order to get what you want you should override the [`onInterceptTouchEvent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) method, like stated [here](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html#intercept):

> The onInterceptTouchEvent() method gives a parent the chance to see
>   any touch event before its children do. If you return true from
>   onInterceptTouchEvent(), the child view that was previously handling
>   touch events receives an ACTION_CANCEL, and the events from that point
>   forward are sent to the parent's onTouchEvent() method for the usual
>   handling. onInterceptTouchEvent() can also return false and simply spy
>   on events as they travel down the view hierarchy to their usual
>   targets, which will handle the events with their own onTouchEvent().

Basically, according to your own logic (button `onTouchEvent`, etc), you should instruct your `ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent()` to return true if `MotionEvent` raw coords are not included in the visible rect of your button.

Comment: I've tried that.  It blocks further events to the button as well as the siblings.  That breaks my button!

Comment: I'm going to post a different question - what I'm really trying to do is prevent siblings from receving onDrag.  I think I'm on the wrong approach looking at MotionEvents.